# Is it possible to use URL folder/path without creating a corresponding directory on the server?

Tags: url, routes, webserver, url-routing

Suppose I have the following URL, which displays some unique information for the specified user:
http://example.com/?user=john-smith

I want this URL to look like this instead, because it's (supposedly) more SEO-friendly and human-readable:
http://example.com/user/john-smith

Of course I can do it by creating a "user/john-smith" sub-directory in the root and putting an index.php or default.htm or whatever in there.
But I might have millions of users and I really don't want to create millions of sub-directories like this (not even sure I can).
So, how can I make it so that a user enters "http://example.com/user/john-smith" in the browser, but arrives or is somehow redirected to "http://example.com/index.php" or whatever it takes to make this work without creating a separate directory for every user? Is this even possible?

Notes:
- The closest I can get to is "http://example.com/user/?john-smith", but that's still not good enough.
- I'm using Windows Server 2016 with PHP 7, but happy to hear solutions for any platform.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally discovered the answer (sadly, no thanks to StackOverflow).
On a Windows Server it's actually pretty easy - IIS 7.0 and later contain a service called "URL Rewrite" (if it's not installed by default, it can be installed separately), which is a surprisingly convenient GUI for creating rules (using standard regular expressions) that convert "incomprehensible" URLs into something that the server understands.
In my example case, I just create a conversion rule from "^user/([a-z-]+)" to "?user={R:1}" and that's it!
There is a similar thing on Apache servers called "mod_rewrite", but you might need to write rules in XML manually for it.